Problem with running a script using selenium python via php
I have a problem with executing a script from the PHP side. If I execute the python script from the console, everything works. If it is executed from php, i.e. via the www-data user, there is a problem.
Hi, I have a problem with executing a script from the PHP side.
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 lms_dodawanie_komputera.py edit '.$cust_id.' "haslo"');

If I execute the python script from the console, everything works. If it is executed from php, i.e. via the www-data user, there is a problem. I suspect that there are files being created somewhere that he doesn't have access to
Part of a Python script:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
...
#laczenie z przegladarka
    chrome_options = Options()
#    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
    chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('–user-data-dir=/root/www-temp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('–profile-directory=www-temp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('–disable-extensions')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),                                                                              options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("URL")
   .....
    return driver

When a normal Linux user runs the script, it works
When I try to invoke the script with sudo -u www-data python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_dodawanie_komputera.py", line 120, in <module>
    wynik = edycja_klienta(id, tekst)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_dodawanie_komputera.py", line 75, in edycja_klienta
    driver = logowanie_do_LMSa()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_dodawanie_komputera.py", line 32, in logowanie_do_LMSa
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55bdcd51e8da <unknown>
#1 0x55bdcd1ece50 <unknown>
#2 0x55bdcd224e05 <unknown>
#3 0x55bdcd220c78 <unknown>
#4 0x55bdcd26d64e <unknown>
#5 0x55bdcd26ce66 <unknown>
#6 0x55bdcd261233 <unknown>
#7 0x55bdcd22f093 <unknown>
#8 0x55bdcd23009e <unknown>
#9 0x55bdcd4e5b3b <unknown>
#10 0x55bdcd4e9af1 <unknown>
#11 0x55bdcd4d1705 <unknown>
#12 0x55bdcd4ea662 <unknown>
#13 0x55bdcd4b68df <unknown>
#14 0x55bdcd50d6d8 <unknown>
#15 0x55bdcd50d8a2 <unknown>
#16 0x55bdcd51d6cc <unknown>
#17 0x7f010da3a134 <unknown>


Then when I try to launch the browser with sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
sudo: nie udało się rozwiązać nazwy hosta HLG-MAIN-BACKUPS: Ta nazwa lub usługa jest nieznana
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.
[176290:176290:0830/160037.628704:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Połączenie zerwane przez drugą stronę (104)
Pułapka debuggera/breakpoint

Debian 12, Selenium, Python, PHP 8
Someone had a similar problem, because the solutions from Google did not work?
I also tried adding an option chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
Then I received it:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_kopia.py", line 121, in <module>
    wynik = edycja_klienta(id, tekst)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_kopia.py", line 76, in edycja_klienta
    driver = logowanie_do_LMSa()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/www/html/lms_system/lms_kopia.py", line 33, in logowanie_do_LMSa
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60,000)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x564c023c58da <unknown>
#1 0x564c02093e50 <unknown>
#2 0x564c020cbe05 <unknown>
#3 0x564c020c7c78 <unknown>
#4 0x564c0211464e <unknown>
#5 0x564c02113e66 <unknown>
#6 0x564c02108233 <unknown>
#7 0x564c020d6093 <unknown>
#8 0x564c020d709e <unknown>
#9 0x564c0238cb3b <unknown>
#10 0x564c02390af1 <unknown>
#11 0x564c02378705 <unknown>
#12 0x564c02391662 <unknown>
#13 0x564c0235d8df <unknown>
#14 0x564c023b46d8 <unknown>
#15 0x564c023b48a2 <unknown>
#16 0x564c023c46cc <unknown>
#17 0x7f01199e2134 <unknown>



Have you tried using chdir() to change to the folder where the command line execution succeeds before executing the command from PHP?

Opera 89 also uses chrome_crashpad_handler.

As well other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4. And in Sublime Text 3 build 4180.
